# Configuring MOSS and Reporting Services on a Domain Controller

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, domain-controller, ssrs

I'm working on a pretty standard MOSS virtual development environment. I have MOSS, sql 2005 and the machine is also the Domain Controller.

I'm now doing some work with Reporting Services (SSRS) and integrating it with MOSS.

I therefore installed SP2 to give me the option in SSRS of SharePoint integrated mode. I also installed the SSRS Add-In for SharePoint.

Then in SSRS I chose to create a new database so that I could tell it to use SharePoint integrated mode and called it reportservermoss, as reportserver had previously been used. I created this and chose all the defaults with integrated authentication.

I then began to configure the SharePoint side of things in Central Administration. Under Grant Database Access I tried to enter the local admin account, this failed until I found this post pointing out a bug, so I changed the servername to it's IP Address and it allowed me to continue.

So I think all is fine. I choose Set Server Defaults in Central Admin and get a large page of html/nonsense beginning:

An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the report server is available and configured for SharePoint integrated mode.

There's nothing in the logs.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a known bug when your using the local admin account to make the connection between reporting services and MOSS. I had to use the static ip address of the server and then enter the local admin account and password when prompted in Grant Database Access Page.

I then stopped and started the windows sharepoint Services service under operations > services.

Then IISReset.

This seemed to do the trick.

Hope this helps someone else get around this.

Any further thoughts on this topic appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're on a Domain Controller so there is no Local Admin account.  Secondly, any SharePoint install on a DC is well known to be fraught with difficulty.  I think that even if you do find a solution for your current problem, there will be other problems in the future.

Comment: This is for a development environment and is pretty common to have everything on one machine. Microsoft even has a VPC pretty similar to this setup that is used for training.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you used the IP address of the machine to connect reporting services. Did you use 127.0.0.1? Do you have a static IP address? Otherwise it could have been that your IP address changed and that the IP you entered in is no longer valid.